# Azure batch task not pulling the base image from docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, azure-batch, azure-container-registry

I am facing a strange problem while running my simple application image (hosted on Azure container registry). When i create a Cloudtask in azure batch to run the image by getting it from azure container registry it seems like the base image of this image is not being pulled from the docker hub (It is my own another image which i pushed to docker hub). The things is when i run the image locally, everthing works as expected (there are different files/folders created in container) but on azure batch (nothing happens). What can be the problem. Thank you.

Results when image is running locally these files are created:

> Before hello world
>
> report.html
>
> run.sh
>
> wkhtmltopdf
>
> After hello world

Results when the imaging is running on Azure batch

> Before hello world
>
> After hello world

Here is the Dockerfile

```
From "usmancombi/imaging"
COPY ./run_all.sh /run_all.sh
RUN dos2unix /run_all.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/run_all.sh" ]
```

Here is the run_all.sh file

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Before hello world"
ls
echo "After hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify if the image is loaded, you can SSH (or RDP) into your compute node and query. However, if you specify the container on the pool, then the compute node will not provision properly if the specified container(s) are not found or loaded correctly.

Most likely, you are seeing the effects of [Azure Batch setting the working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-docker-container-workloads#container-settings-for-the-task) of the container to `$AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR`.

Add `pwd` before `ls` in your script to verify.

Comment: Thanks @fpark for your time. If the container is not found or loaded correctly i expect some kind of error text in stderr or maybe i am wrong in this case? I did put "pwd" before "ls" and the result is :

`Before hello world

/mnt/batch/tasks/workitems/JobPool2018-07-19-20-46-15/job-1/task1/wd

After hello world`

Comment: Any suggestions? :)

Comment: You would get an error if the container image was not loaded. You are seeing exactly the effects of Azure Batch setting the working directory of the container. Please see the referenced document in the answer.